# Как при первом входе на сайт c мобильных отображать иконку на iOS-приложение?

Tags: javascript, адаптивная-верстка, apple

Привет.

Мне довольно не тривиальная задачка пришла, но простая, главное разобраться.
Суть такая:
Есть готовый сайт-SPA и есть готовое мобильное приложение на iOS. 
При первом входе на сайт SPA через устройства на iOS нужно рисовать примерно вот такую плашку с иконкой и ссылкой на мобильное приложение в апп-сторе:

[image: скрин примера]

Как это делается?
Я предполагаю, что нужно просто через window.navigator определять клиент и грузить этот кусок вёрстки, если первый логин, или же в апп-сторе есть какие-то API, через которые это автоматически настроить можно?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно обратиться [к справке](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) и воспользоваться следующим `meta`

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

- `app-id`: (**Обязательно.**) Уникальный идентификатор вашего приложения. Чтобы найти *app ID* в *iTunes Link Maker*, введите имя приложения в поле поиска, и выберите нужные страну и медиа тип. В результатах найдите свое приложение и выберите *iPhone App Link* в колонке справа. Ваш *app ID* - это девятизначное число между *id* и *?mt*.
- `affiliate-data`: (*Опционально.*) Ваша партнерская строка в *iTunes*, если вы партнер *iTunes*. Если нет, смотрите подробнее о партнерстве http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/.
- `app-argument`: (*Опционально.*) *URL* который добавляет контекст вашему нативному приложению. Если добавляете это и пользователь уже установил приложение он может перейти с веб сайта, сразу на соответствующую позицию в приложении.

**Важно:** Вы не можете показывать *Smart App Banners* внутри *frame*. А также, баннеры недоступны в *iOS Simulator*.