# Как создать баннер на сайте, предлагающий установить приложение?

Tags: php, html, мобильные-приложения, предложения

Как можно сделать баннер, чтобы он определял мобильное устройство и предлагал перейти в play market или app store?
Хотелось бы использовать php.

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как при первом входе на сайт c мобильных отображать иконку на iOS-приложение?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546238/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-c-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ios-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Например можно использовать [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) Делаем проверку, в зависимости от типа устройства или операционной системы, выводим нужный банер, например:

```
if( $detect->isAndroidOS() ){
 //здесь вывод баннера для Андроида 
}
if( $detect->isiOS() ){
 //здесь вывод для iOS
}
```

Comment: А как можно именно вывести такой баннер?

Comment: А у Вас страница как формируется?